# How to implement concrete table inheritance pattern in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database-design, inheritance

I want to know how to implement classes in **MySQL** that represent a subset of another class type, with the purpose of having subclasses inherit fields from the parent class. Described by Martin Fowler as the [concrete table inheritance](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/concreteTableInheritance.html) pattern.

An example would be having a `GradStudent` class with two subclasses `TeachingAsst` and `ResearchAsst`--each of which inherit the `firstName`, `lastName`, and `birthDate` fields from `GradStudent` (see [original source](https://web.csulb.edu/colleges/coe/cecs/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=subclass.php)):

[image: UML]

This is the relation scheme diagram that should be implemented:

[image]

**Here's what I've got so far adapted from [here](https://hackernoon.com/mysql-tutorial-example-relation-foreign-key-database-funtion-join-table-query-one-namy-nest-41dd09648fbd):**

```
CREATE TABLE GradStudent (
    studentID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    firstName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    lastName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    birthDate DATE NULL,
    UNIQUE(firstName, lastName, birthDate),
    PRIMARY KEY (studentID)
);

CREATE TABLE TeachingAsst (
    studentID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    courseAssignment VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    PRIMARY KEY (studentID),
    FOREIGN KEY (studentID) REFERENCES GradStudent (studentID)
);

CREATE TABLE ResearchAsst (
    studentID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    researchGrant VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    PRIMARY KEY (studentID),
    FOREIGN KEY (studentID) REFERENCES GradStudent (studentID)
);
```

Is this the correct way to create subclasses in MySQL?

To be more specific, I am not asking for the following:

- Answers describing *single table inheritance* or *class table inheritance* patterns ([discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567935/how-to-do-inheritance-modeling-in-relational-databases))
- Additional types of EER diagram mappings ([discussed here](http://www.agiledata.org/essays/mappingObjects.html))
- Answers describing shared primary keys in general ([discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shared-primary-key))
- Pointers/Links to textbooks and other resources that do not show MySQL code implementing inheritance (such as a list of stack exchange search results for [`[class-table-inheritance]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/class-table-inheritance) or using OOP [classes](https://www.alachisoft.com/resources/articles/inheritance-mapping.html)).

Comment: The scheme is absolutely unclear (now it looks like illogical). Describe all the details of the processes which this scheme must describe verbally, including the smallest and most insignificant. What are `batting_average` and `bowling_average` columns? for each table where these columns are present.

Comment: It's also unclear what you're asking help with since you're already implementing *inheritance* with your example queries via their foreign key relationships. Inheritance in relational databases isn't functionally the same as in an object oriented programming language. There's not really a concept of parent and children tables, rather they're all just siblings, and you define their relationships via foreign keys.

Comment: @Akina Went ahead and modified the example to better represent what I'm looking to accomplish.

Comment: @J.D. I'm looking to avoid redundancy by using subclasses and want to know what's the correct way of implementing subclasses in MySQL.

Comment: As I mentioned, *subclasses* don't really exist as a concept in relational databases. You don't need to repeat fields when the *sibling* tables are related by your foreign keys. Then to access one of those fields, you would just join the two tables together.

Comment: For new scheme the attempt to move courseAssignment and researchGrant into separate tables is obviously illogical, one-table scheme where these columns are moved into is reasonable. PS. Editing the question completely which makes the comments/answers incorrect is a disrespect to the interlocutors. Creaste new question in such case.

Comment: Show us some `SELECTs`.  If they are not too hard to write against the proposed schema, then "ship it!"  (In other words, the textbook terminology should not be taken too seriously.)